# How to update inactive portal user record in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, customer-portal, person-accounts

We enabled Person Accounts in our org and there is a batch apex class that is scheduled to run every morning which does [merging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm) of Accounts in case if there are any duplicates. There is a new ask to update the FederationIdentifier on the portal user associated to the merged account. Merge class makes that portal user inactive by design, I am also trying to append a string '_MERGED' to the federationIdentifier so that we will know what happened when we look back at these records again.

I am updating the User records in the finish method of the batch class by storing fedIds from the Account into a List like below

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
        List<User> loosingAccUsers = new List<User>();
        for(User u : [SELECT Id, FederationIdentifier 
                      FROM User 
                      WHERE FederationIdentifier IN :userFedIds AND IsActive = false])
        {
            u.FederationIdentifier = u.FederationIdentifier+'_MERGED';
            loosingAccUsers.add(u);
        }
        System.debug('LOOSING USERS: '+loosingAccUsers);
        Database.SaveResult[] updateResult = Database.update(loosingAccUsers, false);
        for (Database.SaveResult sr : updateResult) {
            if (!sr.isSuccess()) { 
                for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                    System.debug('ERRORS WHILE UPDATE : => '+err.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

This is working as expected when executed but when I tried to do the same in test class I am getting this error "**You can't create a contact for this user because the org doesn't have the necessary permissions. Contact Salesforce Customer Support for help**." I am only updating the existing user record and not creating any contact. My understanding is that since it is a portal user, system is trying to activate the user by associating a contact to update the record? Does any one know if that is true and is there a way to avoid this error?

TEST CLASS:

```
@isTest
public class AccountMergeBatch_Test {

    @testSetup 
    static void dataSetup()
    {
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        
        for (Integer i=0; i<50; i++) {
            
            //create TO Accounts for Merge
            Account toAct = new Account();
            toAct.FirstName = 'Win';
            toAct.LastName = 'recordw'+i;
            toAct.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
            toAct.FinServ__SourceSystemId__c = String.valueOf(i).length() > 1 ? 'z0000'+i : 'z00000'+i;
            accList.add(toAct);
            
            //create FROM Accounts for Merge
            Account fromAct = new Account();
            fromAct.FirstName = 'Loose';
            fromAct.LastName = 'recordl'+i;
            fromAct.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
            fromAct.FinServ__SourceSystemId__c = String.valueOf(i).length() > 1 ? 'z0000'+i : 'z00000'+i;
            accList.add(fromAct);             
        } 
        
        Database.insert(accList); 

        List<Account> toAccList = [Select Id, LastName from Account where LastName LIKE 'recordw%' ];
        List<Account> fromAccList = [Select Id, LastName from Account where LastName LIKE 'recordl%'];    
        List<Account_Merge__c> accMerge = new List<Account_Merge__c>();
        
        system.debug('this is testfromAccList Size'+fromAccList.size());   
        For(Integer i=0; i<fromAccList.size(); i++) {
            Account_Merge__c am = new Account_Merge__c();
            am.From_Account__c = fromAccList[i].Id ;
            am.To_Account__c = toAccList[i].Id;
            am.To_Be_Merged__c = true;
            am.User_Fed_Id__c  = fromAccList[i].FinServ__SourceSystemId__c;
            accMerge.add(am);               
        } 
        Database.insert(accMerge);
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void testMergingClient()
    {
        List<account> accsCreated = [SELECT Id, recordtype.name, IsPersonAccount FROM account WHERE IsPersonAccount=true];
        system.debug('testsetup acc list size'+accsCreated.size()+ ' has at least one person account: '+accsCreated[0].IsPersonAccount+' RECTYPE NAME: '+accsCreated[0].recordtype.name);

        Profile portalProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='My Customer Self Service' Limit 1];
        List<User> commUsers = new List<User>();
        Integer k=0;
        For(Account a: accsCreated) 
        {
            User commUser = new User();
            commUser.FirstName =a.FirstName;
            commUser.LastName = a.LastName;
            commUser.Email='test.test@testsite.com';
            commUser.ContactId = a.PersonContactId;
            commUser.ProfileId = portalProfile.Id;
            commUser.Username = 'test.test@testsite.com.'+k;
            commUser.Alias = a.LastName.substring(0,6)+k;
            commUser.EmailEncodingKey ='UTF-8';
            commUser.CommunityNickname = a.LastName;
            commUser.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
            commUser.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
            commuser.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
            commuser.FederationIdentifier= 'z'+a.FinServ__SourceSystemId__c.subStringAfter('z');
            commUsers.add(commUser);   
            k++;
        }
        System.debug('COMM USER SIZE: '+commUsers.size());
        Database.insert(commUsers);
        
        Test.startTest(); 
        
        AccountMergeBatch accountMerge = new AccountMergeBatch(); 
        Id jobid= Database.executeBatch(accountMerge,50);
        
        Test.stopTest();
        
        List<Account_Merge__c> mergeRecordsCreated = [SELECT name, To_Be_Merged__c FROM Account_Merge__c];
        system.debug('testsetup clientMerge list size'+mergeRecordsCreated.size());  
        
        List<User> usersCreated = [SELECT Id, FederationIdentifier, IsPortalEnabled, ContactId, Username, IsActive FROM User WHERE Id IN :commUsers];
        system.debug('testsetup usersCreated list size'+usersCreated.size());
    }
    
}
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Test class itself isn't failing with this error but still i want to confirm i am not putting buggy code in the system that will backfire someday later.

Comment: are you testing against a scratch org or a sandbox? Also - a common mistake -- it is `losingAccUsers`, not `loosingAccUsers`

Comment: I’m testing in a sandbox. Thank you for the correction :)